# How to get the value of an input and assign a label which he has no association

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm improving my website, and it has the following dropdown where some can choose the sex:

```html
<h2>Person Sex</h2>
<label for="sex"></label>
<select id="sex">
  <option id="men">Men</option>
  <option id="women">Women</option>
</select>
```

Perfect. To send to my backend is very simple, i just I get the value of #sex id and send too the backend through a ajax.

Now, i want use checkbox's:

```html
    <h1>Person Sex</h1>

    <label for="men">Men</label>
    <input type="radio" id="men"/><br/>
    <label for="women">Women</label>
    <input type="radio" id="women"/>
```

My question is: how can i associate the women or the men to only a label called sex? And how can i make impossible to choose both.

Thanks.

Comment: In terms of label association you could use aria-describeby. In order to make them associate with each other use the name attribute and if you want the ability to select both use check boxes rather than radio types.

Comment: Those are not checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `name` and `value` attributes of the `input`s:

```
<label for="men">Men</label>
<input type="radio" id="men" value="men" name="sex" /><br/>
<label for="women">Women</label>
<input type="radio" id="women" value="women" name="sex" />
```

The `name` field on radio buttons allows them to be grouped. When submitting the form, the `value` of the selected item should be the value of the response for `sex`. For example, `$sex = $_POST["sex"];` in PHP.

If you want a default value for your radio button group:

```
<input type="radio" id="women" value="women" name="sex" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a name that is the same in both radio buttons. That way, only one can be chosen.

```html
    <h1>Person Sex</h1>

    <label for="men">Men</label>
    <input type="radio" id="men" name="sex"/><br/>
    <label for="women">Women</label>
    <input type="radio" id="women" name="sex"/>
```